# Detect when history.pushState is completed

Tags: javascript, pushstate, html5-history

I'm trying to achieve something that I believe to be difficult.

I have this piece of code,

```
(function(history){
    var pushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state) {
        if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") {
            history.onpushstate({state: state});
        }
        // ... whatever else you want to do
        // maybe call onhashchange e.handler
        return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
    }
})(window.history);
```

As you can see, basically, I override the pushState function from the global object history, so I can call another function when this happens and then have a sort of an event handler attached.

It works great, however, **I need to know the final HTML that is being generated from this new url**. I have all my client routing sorted out and the content is being served without page reload, but I just don't know how to get that HTML when there is a history.pushState happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not very clear what *"get that html"*  really means or how it fits in with your routing

Comment: If I made a new request to the server with the url that I'm pushing into history, the server would give me a 200 and the new HTML, right? that is what I would like to get when detecting a pushstate event.

Comment: Should make request to some other path for the html. Also if you are not using url hash for client side routing would need to make sure server is configured for any virtual paths you use client side. Have to consider bookmarks and page refreshes for example

Comment: Exactly the same html is delivered on client and server side routing. We have to keep SEO happy, so that is covered. My only concern is about how to, for example, get the new title of the new url, or if there is any video or audio elements, for example.